# Native vs Cross platform - Messaging app

Tags: ios, cross-platform, react-native, native

Let's say I'm building an app similar to Whatsapp or Facebook messenger.
And consider I'm developing it by myself.

Should I start with:

- a native iOS version only
- a cross platform solution (like react or electron)
- a web only version

Things I'm considering:

- native iOS only is faster to develop
- because it's a messaging app, people might not even try it if it's just on iOS
- I couldn't find a single successful app that was written using a cross platform tool (only Facebook, but it was a long time ago and they rewrote their app)
- I'm not sure if it will make any difference in terms of performance and UX/UI (my guts tell me it won't, because it's a messaging app, not a game or something with fancy animations)
- a web version only would also be fast to develop and it would be available everywhere, but wouldn't have a very good use experience on mobile

What you think?

Answer (score 2):

There are many things in consideration and this question has no right or wrong answer:

so my opinion: 
lets us compare the native vs the x-platform and will see the summary at the end...

---

- Developing a x-platform can be a little slow since you will need to learn a new framework/ and maybe a new Language. after that learning curve, you will be able to do all you need.
- unless you are programming a game or similar app, you need to be careful not developing an app that behaves different as what users use to see and feel with their native apps, not only colors and fonts, but position of Widgets in the view etc. **(native 1 : Xplatform 0)**
- since cross-platform is using a 2nd language for developing, you app will never offer the new features of the changes in every platform (e.g. in android version-L you will use those floating buttons, but you will need to wait until the 2nd language develope their sdk/framework that covers that so you can use)  **(native 2 : Xplatform 0)**
- Depending of what platform you decide to use, there must be a case where the support, bug-fixing or the community to ask questions and resolve issues is well mantened, or available at all, but for sure less content that native **(native 3 : Xplatform 0)**
- some x-platforms use some kind of middle-layer (some of them with web components) wich is bringing you a lack of usability, (e.g delays in events, weird layout formatting etc); that can be very bad for the application and harm the UX-UI, same as point above **(native 4 : Xplatform 0)**
- The cost of developing that kind of apps comparing native to cross-platform is very easy to differentiate and will give you advantage as a x-platform developer. **(native 4 : Xplatform 1)**

  so to summarise, it is always better to go native and in my opinion, only games should be develop with x-platform

  I hope this post gives you a better view of the multiple ways to go to the market....

  at the end is up to you!

Comment: What about being a messaging app, do you think people would use an iOS only version?

Comment: if is iOs only then go native. IMHO